# android widgets by flex

Tags: apache-flex, air, android-widget

does Android allow to develop widgets using flex or air?

Answer (score 3):

From http://webexplorations.com/blog/?p=485

> Can’t use AIR to create Android widgets

Answer (score 2):

Bit more official source: http://www.adobe.com/products/air/faq.html

*"Android widgets are currently not supported in AIR."*

However many has requested this feature.